# XMLHttpRequest responseXML error

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I use XMLHttpRequest for xsl file loading (Internet Explorer 7):

```
var url = "template.xsl";
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var async = false;
request.open("GET", url, async);
request.send();
```

But "request.responseXML" is invalid. Here error information from "request.responseXML.parseError":
- errorCode: -1072896681
- reason: "Invalid xml declaration."
- srcText: ""

Here is the "request.responseText":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
  <!-- content -->  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.. I think respnseText should be empty. did you check request.getAllResponseHeaders() (or .getResponseHeader('Content-Type')) ? The content-type should be text/xml

Also you might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781387/responsexml-always-null)