# responseXML is null

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
url = "http://localhost/xml.php?type=xml";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
      xmlhttp.send(null);
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)  {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if (xmlhttp) {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

alert(xmlhttp.responseXML); //returns null
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<main>
    <food>
        <type>6</type>
        <region>5676</region>
    </food>
    <food>
        <type>6</type>
        <region>5676</region>
    </food>

</main>
```

Anyone has idea why `xmlhttp.responseXML` is returning as null?

Comment: possible duplicate of [responseXML always null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781387/responsexml-always-null)

Comment: In the other question, I think [MooGoo answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781387/responsexml-always-null/3781419#3781419) is more relevant to your case..

Comment: I don't know if this can cause the responseXML to be null, but your XML is invalid. You are using two different tags to open/close: `<type>6</clotheID>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTTP request is asynchronous. `xmlhttp.responseXML` won't have some value until `xmlhttp.readyState` has the value of `4`.

```
var url = "http://localhost/xml.php?type=xml";
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)  {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
if (xmlhttp) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Additionaly, I don't think you need the `setRequestHeader` line. XML MIME type is required for response, not for request. Also, please respect good coding practices (don't forget `var`, DRY, etc.)

Comment: Interestingly, I've just stumbled into a case where responseXML is null even though readyState is 4 and status is 200. Any ideas on what could cause such bizarre behaviour?

Comment: Found a workaround, but I'm still baffled about why the problem is happening:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336381/responsetext-works-but-responsexml-is-always-null
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781387/responsexml-always-null

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have `header('Content-type: application/xml');` in your PHP script.
Additionally, check the responseText - maybe you've got error?

Comment: I know this is a bit late but I ran into this issue while migrating files from one domain to the next. I found a space was created at the start of my xml file which was giving me a readyState of 2 but a 200 status causing the responseXML to be null while response and responseText had a value.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I migrated from Apache to nginx and had this same problem. Everything worked perfectly when loaded as simple files or from the Apache server, but `responseXML` was always null when running on nginx.

My particular situation also involved an XSL stylesheet to transform the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="main-template-transformer.xsl"?>
```

The content type of the regular XML file was coming back just fine. However, what mattered was the content type of the XSL file. *(This was discovered by checking `responseText` which was not null, and contained the entire text of the XSL file. Checking HTTP headers on this file revealed that the content type had changed between Apache and nginx.)*

Content type should be either `text/xml` or `application/xml`. The default in nginx 1.10.3 is `application/octet-stream`, and this will cause `responseXML` to be always null.

This can be fixed by adding the following line to the JavaScript file:

```
xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
```

This can be fixed by adding the following line to the nginx server configuration in "conf/mime.types":

```
    text/xml                              xsl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just testing and found the solution.

I don't kwow why but when you send xml header the XMLHttpRequest is not capable to parse it.

For using DOM responseXML properties of XMLHttpRequest you have to remove the xml header.

In your case the xml response will be

```
<main>
    <food>
        <type>6</type>
        <region>5676</region>
    </food>
    <food>
        <type>6</type>
        <region>5676</region>
    </food>
</main>
```