# ResponseXML returning NULL

Tags: javascript, xml, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [responseXML is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973202/responsexml-is-null)

I have recently started working on javascript. I am trying to parse the RSS feeds by using XMLHttprequest.The responseXML is not returning any data, responseText is returning data.I am passing one URL for the GET method, from where the DOM has to be formed.Even I tried passing a locally placed xml file in place of url,even that does not work.I doubted the cross domain incompatibility for this,but not sure.Can anyone give me some clue about this.If this is a problem of cross-domain request(as I am running my code in localhost and passed url is on another domain), then How can I test this code to be working fine?
Also Can anyone share some sample JS code to parse XML,and store DOM in LocalStorage of HTML5.Any help will be great.

Thanks

Comment: if you dont share your code , how can anybody give you a specific answer ?

Comment: <html> <head> </head> <body> <div id="news"></div> <script type="text/javascript"> var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); request.open('GET', 'http://google.com', false); request.send(null); if (request.status === 200) { //alert(request.responseText); document.getElementById("news").innerHTML=request.responseText; } </script> </body> </html>

Comment: Sorry for replying late.When I Run this Code on Google Chrome browser and Firefox the xmlhttprequest does not succeed.On IE it succeeds.I doubt on the security policy of chrome.I want to get an idea about the behaviour of XMLHttprequest method calls in different browsers, and if at all some security policy blocks cross-domain requests in Chrome, then workarounds for that.

Comment: Also in IE,accessing the URl, may be any URL works when I changed the security policy under Tools->Internet Options->Security->Custom level->Misc->Allow data sources across domains.Can we have some settings like this in Firefox or Chrome where we can allow accessing Domain URLs.In Google Chrome the XMLHttprequest fails and gives the Error:Uncaught Error:NETWORK_ERROR:XMLHttpRequest Exception 101.