# responseText works but responseXML is always null

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax, google-maps

I've looked through every answer i can find on here and can't solve this. 
I'm pretty sure I havn't missed anything obvious.

I'm trying to load map markers based on lat longs. The problem is when I try to return the AJAX response as responseXML its always null, if i use responseText it works fine but obviously the next step doesn't work.

This is the PHP that generates the XML:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
?>    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<properties>
    <![CDATA[
<?php 
if ($body != null): 
        foreach ($body as $property): ?>
        <property>
            <lat><?php echo $property -> lat; ?></lat>
            <long><?php echo $property -> long; ?></long>
            <name><?php echo $property -> property_name; ?></name>
            </property>
<?php endforeach;
endif; ?>
    ]]>
</properties>
```

I can see in Fiddler that the request is made ok

> GET
>   /letsgo/index.php/hotmaps/get_properties_ajax/22.270888501350186/22.288560098193066/114.13720860290528/114.19827713775635
>   HTTP/1.1
>
> Entity Content-type: text/xml

Although when i view this in XML view in fiddler it appears to be empty,

here is the raw response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 15 Jan 2013 11:04:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) PHP/5.4.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 310
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/xml



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<properties>
    <![CDATA[
        <property>
            <lat>22.2776</lat>
            <long>114.173</long>
            <name>Kaxo Tower test</name>
            </property>
        <property>
            <lat>22.2803</lat>
            <long>114.16</long>
            <name>Kuno Tower</name>
            </property>
    ]]>
</properties>
```

Here is the create marker function that is called every time the map is moved

```
// make the ajax request
function loadXMLDoc(downUrl){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

            //var propertiesXml = xmlhttp.responseText; // WORKS FINE!!
            var propertiesXml = xmlhttp.responseXML; // ALWAYS null
            //alert(propertiesXml);     
            var propertiesRows = propertiesXml.getElementsByTagName("property");

            for (var i = 0; i < propertiesRows.length; i++) {           
            var propertiesRow = propertiesRows[i];
            var xmlLat = propertiesRow.getElementsByTagName("lat")[0];
            var xmlLong = propertiesRow.getElementsByTagName("long")[0];
            var propertyLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(xmlLat.firstChild.data),parseFloat(xmlLat.firstChild.data));            
            // create each marker
            createMarker(propertyLatLong);
            }   

        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", downUrl, false); // false or true? makes no difference
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml");
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

and this is the error i get for feeding getElementsByTagName with null, Chrome console says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

This is running on my local Apache

Any suggestions?

/** UPDATE - WORKING CODE **/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEYHERE&sensor=false">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">  

      // initialise map 
      function initialize() {

      // set starting latlong
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(22.2776, 114.173); 

      // set initial map options        
      var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

      // create the map                       
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions); 

      // listen for changes in map bounds - after map has stopped moving!!      
      google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle', function () {      
        loadByBounds(map);          
        });                 
      }

      // if the bounds have changed 
      function loadByBounds(map) {  

        var bounds = map.getBounds();       
        var swPoint = bounds.getSouthWest();
        var nePoint = bounds.getNorthEast();

        // specific co ordinates
        var swLat = swPoint.lat();
        var swLng = swPoint.lng();
        var neLat = nePoint.lat();
        var neLng = nePoint.lng();               

        var downUrl = "<?php echo site_url('hotmaps/get_properties_ajax'); ?>/"+swLat+"/"+neLat+"/"+swLng+"/"+neLng;

        // load the 
        loadXMLDoc(downUrl, map); 

        // clear icons outside of bounding box

        //....


        }

        // make the ajax request
        function loadXMLDoc(downUrl, map){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {

                    var propertiesXml = xmlhttp.responseText; // WORKS FINE!!

                    // remove whitespaces from start and end (.trim() doesnt work)
                    propertiesXml = propertiesXml.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');                 

                    // manually parse to XML DOM object 
                    var parser = new DOMParser();                   
                    var xmlDoc;                 
                       try {
                            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString (propertiesXml, "text/xml");
                        } catch (e) {
                            alert ("XML parsing error.");
                            return false;
                        };

                    //console.log(xmlDoc);

                    // get each property
                    var propertiesRows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("property");   

                    //alert(console.log(propertiesRows));   
                    for (var i = 0; i < propertiesRows.length; i++) {

                        var propertiesRow = propertiesRows[i];
                        var xmlLat = propertiesRow.getElementsByTagName("lat")[0];
                        var xmlLong = propertiesRow.getElementsByTagName("long")[0];
                        var propertyLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(xmlLat.firstChild.data),parseFloat(xmlLong.firstChild.data));           
                        // create each marker
                        createMarker(propertyLatLong, map);
                    }
                 }
             }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", downUrl, false);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml");
            xmlhttp.send(); 
        }   

        // create new markers
        function createMarker(propertyLatLong, map){             
            var dynamicMarker = new google.maps.Marker({

                map:map,
                draggable:false,
                position: propertyLatLong
            });
            debugger;           
        }       
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">      
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try parsing XML yourself:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText, "application/xml");
```

Like this.

Comment: I've gone down the route you suggested and it seems to have worked, although now I'm getting an undefined var error, this may be a separate issue, would you mind having a look? Thanks.

Comment: can you be more specific? which var is undefined on what line?

Comment: Â is not defined fullscreen:104 which would be..
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", downUrl, false);

Comment: Somehow the character Â  had got into line 104, and wasn't visible in aptana, even after deleting all characters where the undefined Â  was showing up, i opened the file in notepad and there it was. Removed that and everything worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

your tags  are in CDATA section so they are ignore as tag by the parser.

Comment: I added the CDATA after reading a reply from somone on a similar post, it makes no difference.

Comment: look at this [link]http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-cdsection and link posted by Lemmy Tauer

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you want the parser to skip almost your entire http response body, it seems there is no need, it's not containing anything that could be misinterpreted. It even is the data you want to get parsed, that you hideaway in your example for no apparent reason.

Look here for some explanation of CDATA:  http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

You could try commenting out the opening and closing CDATA statement like mentioned here: http://de.selfhtml.org/html/xhtml/unterschiede.htm

They also state, that the XML parser assumes UTF-8 encoding by default and will refuse parsing if not configured correctly, and that overwriting the exspected type via the response header is not recommended.

I prefer to avoid opening and closing php blocks inside block-statements the way you did it, but I'm not quite up-to-date with the latest coding conventions, so I may be wrong on that one.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/xml');
header ('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header ('Cache-Control: no-store' , false);

$response ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>';

if ($body != null): 
    foreach ($body as $property):
        $response .='<property>
            <lat>'.$property->lat.'</lat>
            <long>'.$property->long'.</long>
            <name>'.$property->property_name.'</name>
        </property>';
    endforeach;
endif;

$response .='</properties>';

echo responseText;

?>
```

Comment: ok, thanks! I find it easier to read when written the way i had done it if there is a lot of HTML in a view file, also makes finding errors in the HTML a lot easier I find!