# getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null"

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I am trying to parse xml file which is created by using php as shown below.But when I am trying to parse it's data using reponseXML.documentElement i am getting this error in my console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null" here is my code.

```
my javascript code is

function getData()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","data.php",true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            //alert("got response");
            //alert(xhr.responseText);
            var root = xhr.responseXML.documentElement;
            var children = root.childNodes;
            //alert(children.length);
            for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++)
            {
                if(children[i].nodeType == 1)
                {                   
                    var grandChildren = children[i].childNodes;                     
                    for(var j=0;j<grandChildren.length;j++)
                    {
                        if(grandChildren[j].nodeType == 1)
                        {
                            //alert(grandChildren[j].nodeName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}

my xml file is 

<?php  
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" charset="UTF-8"?>';
$aboutMe = "nothing";
$aboutMyFamily = "the best";
$myStreangths = "trying";
$myWeaknesses = "so many";
$personsILike = "SREAA RAAM,SWAAMEE VIVEKAANAMDHA,maamayya";
$thingsILikeInOthers = "honesty,realization";
$thingsIDoNotLikeInOthers = "jealousy,ego";
$myFriends = "bujji";
echo '<data>';
    echo '<profle>';
        echo "<about>";
            echo "'<aboutMe>'.$aboutMe.'</aboutMe>'";
            echo "'<aboutMyFamily>'.$aboutMyFamily.'<aboutMyFamily/>'";
            echo "'<myStrengths>'.$myStreangths.'</myStrengths>'";
            echo "'<myWeaknesses>'.$myWeaknesses.'</myWeaknesses>'";
            echo "'<personsILike>'.$personsILike.'</personsILike>'";
            echo "'<thingsiLikeInOthers>'.$thingsILikeInOthers.'</thingsiLikeInOthers>'";
            echo "'<thingsIDoNotLikeInOthers>'.$thingsIDoNotLikeInOthers.'</thingsIDoNotLikeInOthers>'";
            echo "'<myFriends>'.$myFriends.'</myFriends>'";
        echo '</about>';        
    echo "</profile>";
echo "</data>";
?>
```

Where is the problem???

Comment: possible duplicate of [responseText works but responseXML is always null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336381/responsetext-works-but-responsexml-is-always-null)

Comment: where is the duplication

Comment: of course questions might be same and situations might be same.but there is no solution for this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I may have been too quick to flag as a duplicate. Can you post the output of `xhr.responseText` ?

Comment: xhr.reposntText is working file.it is showing that xml file as text format

Comment: What output do you get if you parse the output yourself? `var parser = new DOMParser(); var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText, "application/xml");`

Comment: when i am alerting using alert(xmlDoc) it is alerting "[object XMLDcoument]"

Comment: i changed that data.php to data.xml and wrote pure xml code in it,though it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem at all. `null` is a documented and correct value for `xhr.resppmseXML`. There is a complete rule-set in **[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)** when the *resppmseXML* field is NULL, so I suggest you take the javascript reference of your choice to make yourself more comfortable with that.

However one hint I can give: This can be NULL because the XML you create is just invalid. When I look at your PHP code I can see that you're creating XML by "hand", that is by concatenating strings. This is often the cause of creating [non-wellformed XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document).

You need to (should) verify the XML you create *before* you send it out with the response to the browser to ensure you haven't made any mistakes creating the XML. I can highly suggest to use an XML library to create the XML instead of creating it by hand. I suggested that for example in previous answers I've been given - but I don't find them right now, so instead I direct you to a reference question which is a bit more broad but should give you some pointers: [How to generate XML file dynamically using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/486757/367456) - but in the end this is you take the XML library of your choice to create (and/or validate) the XML.