# Ajax: responseXML returning null

Tags: xml, ajax

Reading a beginners book for Ajax and the second example is getting XMl data from a php file. I've been stuck for about 2 hours now googling and reading this site's answers to other people's similar problems and I can't figure it out

my function

```
var options;

function getOptions1(){
    var XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "http://localhost/AV/data.php", false); // this was "true" somewhere i read to set it to "false"
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState != 4) return;
        if (this.status == 200){ 
            alert ("hi");
            var xmlDocument = this.responseXML;
            options = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("option"); // firefox tels me here "TypeError xmlDocument is null"
            listOptions();
        }
    }
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
}
```

and here's the data.php file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> //i read to add that encoding in there - no help
    <options>
        <option>red</option>
        <option>green</option>
        <option>blue</option>
    </options>
```

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug, Chrome Inspector or any similar tool to debug the request that you're creating?

Comment: possible duplicate of [responseXML is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973202/responsexml-is-null)

Comment: @Shikiryu This is _not_ the same problem OP is having. His code already checks for the problem that other code had.

Comment: Benjamin's answer solved my problem thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the top of your PHP file (in a php tag):

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

If you don't tell PHP to send the response as `text/xml` chances are it'll send the response as `text/html` which will mean the `responseXML` property will be null.

Also, make sure you're not violating the same origin policy. You need your request to be from the same domain and the same port.

Try changing

```
 XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "http://localhost/AV/data.php", false); // this was "true" somewhere i read to set it to "false"
```

To:

```
 XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "/AV/data.php", false);
```

Comment: the header in php tags fixed it.. this book is 7 years old (ajax for dummies) and this is only the second example.. so far both examples have given me hours of trouble. the c++ book i read cover to cover and didn't have NEAR the amount of frustration as this book is causing me. THANK YOU Benjamin!

edit: also - yes all these files are in the same domain

Comment: @Solus I suggest you read Eloquent JavaScript, it's online and free and updated :) Good luck developing! (P.S. XML itself is ancient, I wouldn't _touch_ it for this sort of thing. Generally, for data and not documents, JSON is the de-facto standard today)

Comment: @BenjaminGuenbaum (How come your name doens't auto fill like other people's? weird..) I just got the book you suggested and will begin reading it soon. This book I was reading is 0 for 3 on it's examples.. stressing out because it doesn't work because the writer didn't proofread their code before publishing it I guess. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Rename the `data.php` file to `data.xml` to avoid any possibility that the PHP processor will trip up on the `<?` and `?>` tags

Comment: I'm assuming he's generating the XML _with_ PHP, otherwise he wouldn't have named it `.php` to begin with.

Comment: Perhaps, but PHP will still have trouble with that first line. Why use PHP to generate such a simple file?

Comment: Fetch options from a database or another data source for example.

Comment: The use of PHP's short open tag (<?) is discouraged (http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) even though the documented default is to have them enabled.