# AJAX documentElement of null

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, document

I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null 
With this code:

```
function respondHandler() {
if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
  if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
    xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
    xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
    message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = message;

}else{
alert('something went really wrong');
}

}

}
```

It first worked, now it borked up. I really don't know what is wrong!

Comment: Sounds like `xmlResponse` is NULL, don't you agree?

Comment: Agree with Jay, also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781387/responsexml-always-null

Comment: First there just came the response out of that. Now it says it is null? The 'fixes' on that post i already tried

Comment: I agree btw on that xmlResponse null is. But there is my question then, why is it null? It shouldn't be

Answer (score 0):

man.

### Try this

```
function respondHandler() {
  // get element reference here
  var element = document.getElementById('output');
  if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
    if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
      xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
      xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
      message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
      element.innerHTML = message;

  }else{
    alert('something went really wrong');
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not work, still the same error. In fact, you are doing the same thing as me. But then with an extra variable.

Comment: lol. my bad, man. I'd explain why I thought that'd fix it, but I was mistaken as to what the problem was. So, For us to answer this question quickly, we'd benefit from more context (e.g. are you making cross-domain requests?). What is your code, in full, for the ajax request?