# AJAX Error when attempting to read xml file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I'm trying to retrieve some data from an xml file using ajax

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding=UTF-8"?>

  <user>
     <u_idno>1</u_idno>
     <u_name>nobody</u_name>
     <u_srnm>nothing</u_srnm>
     <u_role>linux</u_role>
  </user>

  <user>
     <u_idno>2</u_idno>
     <u_name>yesbody</u_name>
     <u_srnm>something</u_srnm>
     <u_role>administrator</u_role>
  </user>
```

but I am getting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

I am unsure why it would say null and I've been googling furiously to find out what I've done wrong but I'm clueless. My javascript is as followed

```
  function f_ajax() {

     var lv_request;

     try {
        lv_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } catch (error) {
        lv_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }

     lv_request.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(lv_request.readyState == 4 && lv_request.status == 200) {

           lv_xml = lv_request.responseXML;
           lv_row = lv_xml.getElementsByTagName("user");
           lv_output = null;

           for (lv_cnt = 0; lv_cnt < lv_row.length; lv_cnt++) {

              lv_output = lv_output + lv_row[lv_cnt].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

           }

           document.getElementById("h2_ajax").innerHTML = lv_row;

        }

     }

     lv_request.open("GET", "data.xml", true);
     lv_request.send();

  };

  f_ajax();
```

Comment: What's in `lv_request.responseText`?

Comment: It outputs the entire xml file

Comment: If the value you are seeing in `responseText` is not fully-valid XML you will see a NULL in `responseXML`.

Comment: Take a look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781387/responsexml-always-null -- in particular the answer that talks about parsing the `responseText` back to an XML document (i.e. the answer from Kenny).

Comment: Your opening `<u_role>` tag doesn't match the closing `</role>` tag. Is that a copying error or in the real file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is not well formed. It is missing a root and has some other issues. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <user>
   <u_idno>1</u_idno>
   <u_name>nobody</u_name>
   <u_srnm>nothing</u_srnm>
   <u_role>linux</u_role>
 </user>
 <user>
   <u_idno>2</u_idno>
   <u_name>yesbody</u_name>
   <u_srnm>something</u_srnm>
   <u_role>administrator</u_role>
 </user>
</root>
```

Comment: Those incorrect closing tags were a typo in my question but it was the root tags that fixed it, I didn't know I needed a master parent, thanks so much