# XML in Polymer template with iron-ajax - handle-as, adding XML DOM to template

Tags: ajax, xml, polymer

I'm writing my first Polymer app, which should allow people to read Greek texts from the Bible. I'm trying to read an XML file to create a DOM, then use it in a template.

In `<iron-ajax>`, does `handle-as="xml"` work?  This bug suggests that it might not:  https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/issues/53

The following code loads a file if I change `handle-as="xml"` to `handle-as="text"`, but (obviously) the result is just a bunch of text with angle brackets, not an XML DOM.  It does not work if I change it to `handle-as="document"`:

```html
<template>

  <iron-ajax auto
    url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biblicalhumanities/greek-new-testament/master/syntax-trees/nestle1904-lowfat/xml/04-john.xml" 
    handle-as="xml"   
    last-response="{{response}}"
    >
  </iron-ajax>

  [[response]]

</template>
```

See this Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ByMHcM7xciS2JkkF3MXI?p=preview

The above code is in `content-el.html`.  It works if you change `handle-as="xml"` to `handle-as="text"`.

Questions:

1. Is my problem with `handle-as="xml"` due to the bug in https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/issues/53, or am I thinking this wrong?
2. I assume I could retrieve the text, parse it as XML, and put that result where [[response]] occurs in the template.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the relevant parts of the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML) you need:

> The `XMLHttpRequest.responseXML` property is [...] `null` if the request was unsuccessful, has not yet been sent, or if the retrieved data can't be correctly parsed as XML or HTML.
>
> [...]
>
> If the server doesn't specify the `Content-Type` header as `"text/xml"` or `"application/xml"`, you can use [`XMLHttpRequest.overrideMimeType()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/overrideMimeType) to force `XMLHttpRequest` to parse it as XML anyway.

In the handler of the [`<iron-ajax>.response`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/iron-ajax#event-response) event, if we log the XHR's response (i.e., `event.detail.response.xhr.responseXML`), we see it's `null`, which indicates one of failure conditions mentioned in the MDN docs above. It's likely that the response body couldn't be parsed properly because of an unexpected `Content-Type`.

In your case, the server is responding with a `Content-Type` of `text/plain` despite the request header containing `Accept: text/xml`, which causes a parser error, leading to a `null` for `responseXML`.

[image]

We can fall back to the workaround indicated by the MDN docs to use `XMLHttpRequest.overrideMimeType()` to force the parsing of the contents as XML regardless of its `Content-Type`. This can be done in an [`<iron-ajax>.request`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/iron-ajax#event-request) event handler (fired before the request is sent):

```
<iron-ajax auto
  url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biblicalhumanities/greek-new-testament/master/syntax-trees/nestle1904-lowfat/xml/04-john.xml" 
  handle-as="document"
  headers='{"Accept": "text/xml"}'
  last-response="{{response}}"
  on-request="_onRequest"
  >
</iron-ajax>

// script
_onRequest: function(e) {
  const req = e.detail.request;
  req.xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ggayOx?editors=1010)

Also see related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781419/6277151).

Comment: Excellent answer - thanks!  Clearly written, and precisely answers my question.

Comment: @user430799 No problem :)